# How can I open a file in visual studio code's text editor from the visual studio code's terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, workflow

Trying to start with VSC and want to know if there is a shortcut to open VSC's text editor from it's terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have added vscode to your `PATH` variable during the installation process you can just type `code path/to/your/file`. This will open the file in the current vscode instance.
If you want it to open in a new window add the `-n` flag. For example `code path/to/your/file -n`